# libopencv_highgui.so.3.2 not found

Tags: linux, opencv, darknet, yolov4

I am linux ubuntu 20.4 user. I was trying to execute my code :

```
./darknet detector test ~/Documents/Data_challenge/Apple_detection_via_YOLOV4/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/obj.data ~/Documents/Data_challenge/Apple_detection_via_YOLOV4/main_folder/yolov4-tiny-test.cfg ~/Documents/Data_challenge/Apple_detection_via_YOLOV4/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/backup/yolov4-tiny-train_best.weights -thresh 0.20 -dont_show -out ~/Documents/Data_challenge/Apple_detection_via_YOLOV4/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/Prediction.csv < ~/Documents/Data_challenge/Apple_detection_via_YOLOV4/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/test.txt
```

This code took me this output

```
./darknet: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_highgui.so.3.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched what libraries is missing :
[`ldd darknet`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM43q.png)

So, I tried to find if libopencv_highgui.so.3.2 exist and where it is located : [sudo find / -name "libopencv_hig*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfwfi.png).

Then, it means libopencv_highgui.so.3.2 doesn't exist. I looked some forum about this problem :

- [@DavidChenTaipei](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/1959) (12 Dec 2019)
- [@guerillagorilla](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/382#issuecomment-353793523) (24 Dec 2017)

but they doesn't work on my situation.

Comment: so where did you get that `./darknet` from? it clearly needs an incredibly outdated version of OpenCV, so you either need to find binaries of that ancient version, or you need to rebuild darknet to use a more current version of OpenCV

Comment: Does This help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621706/libopencv-highgui-so-4-4-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-direct